# Beamer slides slow to change when using media9

Tags: beamer, media9

I'm successfully using the `media9` package to compile presentation pdf's with embedded *mp4* files.  The problem is that after the video is done, and I am ready to change to the next slide, it takes at least 10 seconds until the pdf renders the next page.  I usually work in Linux, but I'm trying to use Windows just to play this presentation.  I'm using `MiKTeX 2.9` to compile the slides, and the version of `media9` compiled on March 27, 2013.

My slide is as follows:

```
\begin{frame}[c]
  \begin{center}
    \includemedia[ label=vidA, 
           activate=onclick, 
           width=.95\textwidth,
           addresource=http://localhost//vid_mod.mp4,
           flashvars={src=http://localhost//vid_mod.mp4}
           ]{\fbox{~}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

I have tried using `VPlayer.swf`, and the videos did not play at all.  I have also tried embedding the videos directly into the pdf i.e. not using a local webserver, and I get the same behavior.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The `deactivate=onclick` option definitely seemed to help the situation significantly!  Thanks for the advice.  If you make it an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for `VPlayer` not working might be a wrong FlashVar for setting the video source. It must read `source=...` for `VPlayer`, while `src=...` for Strobe.

Try `deactivate=onclick`. This keeps the video + player app loaded when leaving the slide, and might reduce latency.

Comment: But wouldn't that sort of hang Acrobat?, I mean if all the videos keep playing in the background at the same time?

Comment: @alfC: It would be worth a try :)